# "<someone>'s" vs. "for <someone>"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, possessives

It is Mary's birthday. I've bought a present for her.
We say: It is *a present **for Mary**.*
Is it also correct to say: It is ***Mary's*** present?
Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: In most contexts they both mean exactly the same thing. But sometimes *Mary's present* might mean a present ***from*** Mary, so there might feasibly possibly be a context where it's actually *better* to explicitly use the preposition rather than the genitive form. Other than that, it's largely a stylistic choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your comment would be a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

The form:

> That is Mary's X.

is the possessive form, and it means that X is associated with Mary somehow.

For example:

> That is Mary's car.

usually means we are talking about the car that Mary *owns*, but, in the context of, say, a [soapbox derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_Box_Derby), it could mean, "that's the car that Mary *built*," or, if we were a large group of coworkers at a rental car agency, it could mean, "that's the car that Mary *will be driving*." If we were at an art exhibit, it could mean, "that's a picture of a car that Mary *painted*," and if Mary is a Formula-1 race car driver, it could mean, "that's Mary's car *that just crashed*," particularly if we end it with an exclamation point, like this:

> That was Mary's car!

---

It the case of giving gifts, you've correctly supplied one possible meaning:

> It's the present I *intend to give to* Mary.

Although FumbleFingers correctly pointed out there are *other* possible interpretations that are also valid:

> That's the present I *received from* Mary.